# Как подружить prettier и eslint при использовании табов, и пробелов для выравнивания

Tags: javascript, jsx, prettier, linter

В строке 27 преттиер ставит два таба для выравнивания

Кусок кода из компонента Реакт jsx:

[image: код]

Нужно сделать так, чтобы eslint не ругался и не подсвечивал.

Текст ошибки: - Line 27:2:  Mixed spaces and tabs  no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs

Правила Eslint -
indent: ['off'],
'no-tabs': 'off',

Правила Prettier - tabWidth: 2, useTabs: true,

no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs: ["error", "smart-tabs"]
Нашел такую настройку, которая должна бы вроде помочь, но результата ноль, может я настройки неправильно прописываю, если кто знает как правильно сконфигурировать, что бы не отключать проверку отступов полностью - напишите, пожалуйста конфиг.

Comment: Пишет явно - нельзя миксовать табуляцию и пробелы

Comment: Дак преттиер сам почему то использует табы и пробелы, я не понимаю как это пофиксить.

Comment: useTabs: false,

Comment: useTabs: false - меняет использование табов на пробелы, но мне нужны табы в описании об этом указано.

Comment: Есть подоздрение, что так и должно быть https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tabs
(Tabs will be used for indentation but Prettier uses spaces to align things, such as in ternaries.)